# MIT Shared Memory Extension or MIT-SHM over ssh

Tags: ssh, x11, lxc, xauth

I successfully created a `privileged lxc archlinux container` on an archlinux host with lxc. I set up a static ip via dnsmasq and ssh into it and I use `xauth` to forward `X11`. I then call programs like `mupdf` or plot functions from programming languages such as `R` or `Matlab`. While this all works fine I constantly see error messages printed to the console when I open a `*.pdf` file with `mupdf`:

```
     ximage: disabling shared memory extension: BadAccess (attempt to access private resource denied)
```

Two short questions about this:

1. What exactly does this error message mean?
2. How can this error be solved (or is it safe to ignore)?

Answer (score 10):

Shared memory is a mechanism to exchange rendered image without having to use sockets, the protocol works something like this: X client create the shared buffer, X client tell the server `that's where you will find the images i create`, the server "attach" itself to the shared memory and refresh whenever there is an update, this mechanism offers 10x the speed of socket transfer, but slower than zero-copy rendering. 
if you wish you can disable this mechanism by setting these environment variables:

```
QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1
_X11_NO_MITSHM=1
_MITSHM=0
```